# Deserialize JSON to?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have JSON which I need to deserialize, but I don't want to create class with property name.

here's what I get in JSON:

```
"[{"id":1,"width":100,"sortable":true}, {"id":"Change","width":100,"sortable":true}]"
```

So how could I do this?

Thanks for advance:)

Comment: What library are you using for the deserialization?

Comment: Which language are you using, c#
You can use dynamic class [link][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Comment: I have Newtonsoft.Json It's provided with Nhibernate i guess

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json is used by a lot of libraries. And you can get it very simply with NuGet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
var list = new JavaScriptSerializer()
                  .Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(json);

var id = list[0]["id"];
```

Or if you want,  [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
var list2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(json);
```

Json.Net also allows you to use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

```
dynamic list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var wdth = list[0].width;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx), you can deserialize directly to an anonymous class:

```
var json = "[{\"id\":1,\"width\":100,\"sortable\":true}, \"id\":\"Change\",\"width\":100,\"sortable\":true}]";

var myExempleObject = new {id = new object(), width = 0, sortable = false};

var myArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, new[] {myExempleObject});
```

I'm assuming here id can be any object (as in your exemple it can be an int or a string), width must be an int and sortable must be a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You may use json.net

I am not sure if it is what you are looking for.

```
   string json = @"{
    'CPU': 'Intel',
    'PSU': '500W',
    'Drives': [
      'DVD read/writer'
      /*(broken)*/,
      '500 gigabyte hard drive',
      '200 gigabype hard drive'
    ]
}";

JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
while (reader.Read())
{
  if (reader.Value != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}, Value: {1}", reader.TokenType, reader.Value);
  else
    Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}", reader.TokenType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "[{\"id\":1,\"width\":100,\"sortable\":true}, {\"id\":\"Change\",\"width\":100,\"sortable\":true}]";
        JArray array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JArray;
        if (array != null)
        {
            foreach (JObject jObj in array)
                Console.WriteLine("{0,10} | {1,10} | {2,10}", jObj["id"], jObj["width"], jObj["sortable"]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```